# How to catch flaky Internet connections

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where the user has a Wi-Fi connection, but the Wi-Fi is not connected to the Internet.

So navigator.onLine produces a true, but in reality the user is not online.
Short of doing an actual ajax call, is there another indicator to tell whether we’re online or not?

I seem to remember that PhoneGap had an extra indicator.

Comment: Different environments/devices will have different options. Your best cross-platform solution would be a faint polling that pings an end point at a set interval. If you have a few dropped requests, you assume the user is offline.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'http://www.google.com', false);
req.send(null);
if(req.status == 200)
   alert(req.responseText);
```

Comment: What is `proxy.php` in this case? OP mentioned PhoneGap

Comment: You can't connect directly to `http://www.google.com`, it's a cross-domain security limitation.

Comment: and you really only need a 'HEAD' request

Answer (score 3):

Only reliable way really is to try to reach something out there. It can be done hitting against some file of your own site.

```
i_am_online = true;

function connectivity_test()
{
    if (navigator.onLine) // have network, test if can actually reach the server
    {
        $.ajax('/some_static_file.html', { type: 'HEAD', cache: false })
        .done(function() { setTimeout(connectivity_test, 2000); i_am_online = true; })
        .fail(function() { setTimeout(connectivity_test, 2000); i_am_online = false; });
    }
    else // without network I'm offline, no need to ping
    {
        setTimeout(connectivity_test, 2000);
        i_am_online = false;
    }
}

connectivity_test();
```

This should test for peer connectivity every 2 seconds and update the variable `i_am_online` with `true` or `false` accordingly.

Test against some static file to make sure you won't trigger server-side scripts. The method `HEAD` will cause only the headers to be sent, so this "ping" will generate minimal network traffic regardless of the file size.

Comment: Oh!  That's a good idea.  I was starting to write an ajax request, but your idea is simply polling the http server whereas mine would have required going all the way to the database.

Comment: I wonder if this kind of polling would drain the battery. Is it enough to put it into the NowOnline function that gets called when the online event is fired?

Comment: @Phillip Good point. I guess this test can be fired only when the `online/offline` event listener is triggered.

Comment: Oh wait.  If the event says it's online, and our verification says it's not, then we'll never get another online event.  So polling might be necessary after all. I just wouldn't do it every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.addEventListener("online", NowOnline, false);
window.addEventListener("offline", NowOffline, false);
```

Comment: How would it check the state? Just curious

Comment: I was just pointing out the other part of the equation that the author might not be aware of.

Comment: I understand that, my point was: what does `"online"` event exactly mean in this case?

Comment: Online means networking. Networking doesn't mean you can reach every server in the world. In fact even in the Internet this isn't true. So checking if you are "online" by the mere definition may be not a satisfying status to know if you can connect to your server.